# DocuSign sending to a distribution list

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible for me to send a DocuSign envelope to a distribution list (user A, user B, user C...) where whoever opens the email (user A) gets automatically signed into their DocuSign account. Then, user A would be able to sign using their DocuSign credentials. I have read about establishing an Any Signer Group within DocuSign, but I wanted to do this using Office 365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly possible. There is a new feature called "signing groups" which is an evolution of the current "Any Signer" method. You do need to designate the users in the group ahead of time however.

https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/cdse-user-guide/Content/advanced-sending/using-signing-groups.htm

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for, this would require me to manage the groups within DocuSign, but I want to manage the groups in Office 365. I understand that if it is not possible, then I will settle for using Signing Groups.

Comment: The only other option I can mention for signing groups is there is an new API available for this and you can update the signing groups programmatically on a nightly/batch job basis.